# How to position widgets in a custom way

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android app i show a custom dialog. In this dialog i have an icon to be showed to the left, a text to be showed adjacent to the icon (horizontally) and a listview to be showed at the bottom. I can't get this setting the dialog layout horizontal or vertical.
How can i do?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two LinearLayouts. The first should be vertical.

In this one, there should be two items. First another LinearLayout that is horizontal with the Icon and the Text in it. And the other item in the vertical Layout should be the ListView.

Something like that:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="whatever"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="whatever"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a custom layout for your dialog and pass the root View object or layout resource ID to setContentView(View). :

```
customDialog = new Dialog(Activiyt.this);
customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
customDialog.show();
```

Please check this thread for more details :

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application